# How to create sql for friendship relationship (mysql)?

Tags: mysql

I have a mysql Table:

friends(id, userid, friendid)

and a table users (id, username)
ex:

```
(1,'John'), (2, 'Jerry'), (3, 'Larry), (4, 'Marry')
```

John and Jerry are friends, so In friends we have

```
(1,2)
(2,2)
```

and Larry has requested John to be John's friends who had not accepted it

```
(3,1)
```

and John has requested Marry, who di dnot accept it

```
(1,4)
```

Is there a way to do a SQL to get something result for John's friends:

```
(1, Jerry)
```

In all table we have

```
(1,2)
(2,2)
(3,1)
(1,4)
```

Comment: to me this seems really unclear, in my head, I'd do the tables like this: `users`, `user_friend_reqs`, `user_friends` and join them using `users`.`pk_id` ?

Comment: Of course there's a way.

Comment: `(2,2)` ? Shouldn't that be `(2,1)`?

Comment: Tip: Don't mix together two different functions (friendship and friend request). Don't require two records to define one friendship. This both increases the chances of errors as well as complicating your programming enormously.

Answer (score 0):

```
select u.*
from friends f1
join friends f2 on f2.user_id = f1.friend_id
join users u on u.id = f1.friend_id
where f1.user_id = 1 -- John's id
```

Joining the `friends` table with itself will ensure that the "friendship" is "bidirectional".